# How to pass variable when appendchild from anotehr script in javascript ?

Tags: javascript

As title, I use JS load another JSfile,
it's work in new JSfile, but cannot pass var back,
I set it as global var, but it's work like local var.

```
// index.html .js code
function loadScript(url){
    var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
}
loadScript("td01.js");
console.log("when run index: td01_var = " + td01_var);
```

.

```
// td01.js code
td01_var = "td01varValue"
console.log("when run td01.js: td01_var = " + td01_var);
```

> ### console log
>
> ⓧUncaught ReferenceError: td01_var is not defined(…)
>
> when run td01.js: td01_var = td01varValue

Comment: You're not showing where you define `td01_var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try following...

```
// index.html .js code
function loadScript(url){
    var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
}
loadScript("td01.js");

window.onload = function()
{
   console.log("when run index: td01_var = " + td01_var);
}
// this will wait till your js file gets load...
```

Comment: @JoyceBritneyXiang : you can mark this as a correct one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a script element, setting it's source, and appending it to the document loads the script **asynchronously** with the loading code.

You could try setting a load event listener on the script to continue after the script has loaded.

```
function loadScript(url, onLoad){
    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.onload = onLoad;
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function scriptLoaded() {
    console.log("after loading td01.js: td01_var = " + td01_var);
}

// Call loadScript with onLoad callback
loadScript("td01.js", scriptLoaded);
```

Answer (score 0):

As **Traktor53** mentioned, your `loadScript` function loads the script **asynchronously**. Trying to access the var from the other file does not work immediately after the call to load it because the network request to load the file is incomplete.

Some quick googling [lead to this article from 2009](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/), but it's still an effective technique.

**Here's a working Example:**

```js
// See: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/
function loadScript(url, callback) {

  var script = document.createElement("script")
  script.type = "text/javascript";

  if (script.readyState) { //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
        script.readyState == "complete") {
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
        callback();
      }
    };
  } else { //Others
    script.onload = function() {
      callback();
    };
  }

  script.src = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

// Using underscore from a cdn here so we can load an actual file
// Any valid script URI should work, however
var url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"

var onScriptLoaded = function() {
  console.log("Script Loaded", _)
}

// Call loadScript
loadScript(url, onScriptLoaded);
```